# Design Pattern for invoking a Parser in a callback

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I have an application that invokes callback function when a certain action is performed on the application.

Inside this callback function, I would like to invoke a Parser (a command line parser for instance).

This Parser would be running in a while loop and exits and comes back to the callback only when the user uses the command 'quit' on the command line.

Inside the while loop, the user always has access to the command line. Based on the user input on the command line, the Parser takes a unique action. For instance, it will set a variable and it goes to a database like so:

```
command-line>a 100
command-line>
```

Here the parameter `a` in DB would be set to 100.

I want to model the Parser using Object-Oriented Design. Which Design Pattern can I use in this case?

Comment: You sure you need some really fancy pattern? I'd just make the parser a class with a function like `parseCommand(std::string command)` and call that one from your while loop which reads from the users input/command line. EDIT: Oh you want a design for the parser itself after all, or only for the invocation step as your title implies?

Comment: Sounds like [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Running a command interpreter in a callback sounds likely to lock up.

Comment: Having what is effectively a *shell* that do callbacks is quite natural, not the other way around. And a simple input parser just reads one full line of input, splits it on space (trivial if you don't have to worry about quoted strings), and check the first sub-string for the "command" to call, and then call its corresponding function passing a vector of the arguments.

Comment: And unless you want the shell lock up the process, then there are a few solutions to that as well. For example to split the shell and the rest of the processing into separate threads. Or you could poll the standard input to see if there's something to read available, if not then do a little processing otherwise read and handle one single command.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, most design patterns are obsoleted by the introduction of first-class functions. What you need is a dispatch table of names to actions, which is basically [the Command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

Assuming the following definitions:

```
using Tokens = std::vector<std::string>;
using Action = std::function<void(const Tokens&)>;

Tokens read_and_tokenize_line();
void larger_command(const Tokens&);

std::map<std::string, Action> dispatch_table = {
    {"a", [&](const Tokens& tokens){ my_database->set("a", tokens[1]); }},
    {"larger_command", &larger_command},
};
```

You could write your core loop as follows:

```
while (true) {
    auto tokens = read_and_tokenize_line();
    if (tokens[0] == "quit")
        break;
    if (auto it = dispatch_table.find(tokens[0]); it != dispatch_table.end()) {
        it->second(tokens);
    } else {
        std::cerr << "command " << tokens[0] << " not known" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem you have is that your parser run in a `while` loop and that will obviously block your UI. I assume this issue is the (unstated) problem you are trying to solve.

First, there exist parsers that don't need to run in a while loop. `bison` can generate such parsers when in `push` [mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Push-Parser-Function.html). By using this kind of parser you can still rely on your main GUI event loop and feed the parser with tokens inside a callback without blocking.

Then, if you are writing yourself a recursive-descent parser, you can generate a parser that will interrupt itself and save its state each time it needs some input. This is going to be very tricky as you have to save the whole state of the parser including its stack. The way to do it is to use an explicit stack (or many stacks, one for each operand type) for all functions and rewrite the function calls as a big loop inside a switch statement. This is (very) hard and not maintainable. You can start by reading [this article](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html) (which deals with a simpler version of the problem).

Finally, you can use a background thread to host your parser's while loop. Send data to the parser using a pipe or a queue with a semaphore (if you can customize the input method). The issue here is that this background thread will (probably) not be able to update the UI because most framework are not thread-safe. So you will need a mechanism to send back information from the parser to the main UI thread (something like [PostMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagea).

*References*

- Bison - push-parser interface, GNU, https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Push-Parser-Function.html
- Coroutines in C, Simon Tatham, https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html
- Win32 API - PostMessage, Microsoft, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagea